# String Array in C# with dynamic size

Tags: c#

```
public string[,] SqlcodeDeclarations { get; set; }
```

How do i implement "string array" with dynamic size excluding Generic List.

Comment: Why won't you use Lists ?

Comment: There's no way to declare a dynamic sized array. [_The number of dimensions and the length of each dimension are established when the array instance is created. These values can't be changed during the lifetime of the instance._](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d.aspx). As MairajAhmad mentioned you should use Lists. Keep in mind that `T[]` and `List<T>` are both implementing [`IList<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6(v=vs.110).aspx) (`Add()` will throw an exception for arrays) Maybe this is an option.

Comment: You can't have a dynamically sized array, that's what Collections are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a pretty simple class that will let you simulate a dynamic array without exposing it's add/remove methods etc (you can control the methods you expose).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DynamicArray<int> intArray = new DynamicArray<int>(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
            foreach (var number in intArray)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(number.ToString());
            }
            Console.WriteLine("The Second Element is: " + intArray[1].ToString());
            intArray[1] = 6;
            Console.WriteLine("Changed to 6: " + intArray[1].ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key...");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }

    public class DynamicArray<T> : IEnumerable<T> where T: struct
    {
        private List<T> _items = new List<T>();

        public DynamicArray(params T[] items)
        {
            _items.AddRange(items);
        }

        public T this[int index]
        {
            get { return _items[index]; }
            set { _items[index] = value; }
        }

        public int Count { get { return _items.Count; } }

        public void AddNew(T item)
        {
            _items.Add(item);
        }
        public void RemoveAt(int index)
        {
            _items.RemoveAt(index);
        }
        public void Remove(T item)
        {
            _items.Remove(item);
        }

        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return _items.GetEnumerator();
        }

        System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return _items.GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this syntax:

```
int[] array = new int[aDynamicValue];
```

This is how arrays are implemented behind the scenes. You can then resize the array like this:

```
Array.Resize(ref array, anotherDynamicValue;
```

Quick breakdown:
Array.Resize is a static method call.

ref array allows the method to use the same memory you do, instead of passing in a copy. If your a beginner and don't understand, just know that the ref is important.

anotherDynamicValue is a example variable that can be replaced with anything.